# Encrypting strings with more than 256 length in AES-GCM-256 PHP

Tags: php, aes-gcm

I'm trying to encrypt string which is typed in textarea tag or a text input and length of typed string is more than 256 characters.
When length of string in textbox reaches 257 I cannot decrypt it anymore!
I written below codes using sample code on GitHub for AES-GCM encryption it works for short strings but doesn't work for strings more than 256 length.
I search about AES-GCM-256 which I found that there is no (at least easy way) possible way to increase it from 256 to 512 or more which it also make no sense why we do it as it is NOT necessary AT ALL.
I receive error on decrypting of string with length more than 256 which says:
**Authentication failed! because key is over size of 256.**
This is because string length is more than 256!
**Now my question is, how can I encrypt strings more than 256 length? With what method should I encrypt and store long strings in database using AES-GCM in php?**
In below attached codes I tried to encrypt sample string then send it to database.
Then I tried to get data from database by calling ID of any data inserted (recently or old data) so I can get information about that column.
[This is link to AES-GCM library for PHP.](https://github.com/sop/gcm)
**Update:** 
This is exact error I receive on decrypting:
**Fatal error: Uncaught Sop\GCM\Exception\AuthenticationException: Authentication failed. in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\sop\gcm\lib\GCM\Cipher\AES\AESCipher.php:124 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\sop\gcm\lib\GCM\AESGCM.php(54): Sop\GCM\Cipher\AES\AESCipher->nativeDecrypt('\x18\x9CTV\xDBI!<\x9B\l\xFD\xC5\x05#...', '\xA9W\xD5\x94d\x1E\xD2\xC9\xD5 \x91\xA4\xFBT\x8C...', 'ER8BqF&@R%*#tNt...', '&F=VmZ#gP2udV4H...', '^\xBB\xDF\x81\x91\xEF\xFC\xBE\xAD\xDC\x96\x89\xA6\x01\xDE...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php(49): Sop\GCM\AESGCM::decrypt('\x18\x9CTV\xDBI!<\x9B\l\xFD\xC5\x05#...', '\xA9W\xD5\x94d\x1E\xD2\xC9\xD5 \x91\xA4\xFBT\x8C...', 'ER8BqF&@R%*#tNt...', '&F=VmZ#gP2udV4H...', '^\xBB\xDF\x81\x91\xEF\xFC\xBE\xAD\xDC\x96\x89\xA6\x01\xDE...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php(55): getInformation->getData() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\sop\gcm\lib\GCM\Cipher\AES\AESCipher.php on line 124**

```
//Encrypt and Insert data
$cipher = $_POST['textbox_value'];
if($insert = $this->conn()->prepare("INSERT INTO security_check (cipher,aad,sec_key,iv,auth_tag) VALUES (:cipher,:aad,:secKey,:iv,:aTAg)")){

    $aad = 'thisisadditional';
    // encryption key
    $key = 'thisismysecurekey';
    // random initialization vector
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64);
    // encrypt and generate the authentication tag
    [$ciphertext, $auth_tag] = AESGCM::encrypt($cipher, $aad, $key, $iv);

    $bsCipher = bin2hex($ciphertext);
    $bsAAD = bin2hex($aad);
    $bsKey = bin2hex($key);
    $bsIV = bin2hex($iv);
    $bsTag = bin2hex($auth_tag);

    $insert->bindParam(":cipher",$bsCipher,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insert->bindParam(":aad",$bsAAD,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insert->bindParam(":secKey",$bsKey,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insert->bindParam(":iv",$bsIV,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insert->bindParam(":aTAg",$bsTag,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($insert->execute()){
        return "Data encrypted";
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
//Get Data, decrypt it then display it
$column = $_POST['id_of_inserted_data'];

if($select = $this->conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM security_check WHERE id = :col_id")){
    $select->bindParam(":col_id",$column,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $select->execute();
    $plaintext = "";
    $securities = array();
    if($select->rowCount()){
        while($rows = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $securities = [$rows['cipher'],$rows['auth_tag'],$rows['aad'],$rows['sec_key'],$rows['iv']];
        }
        $select = null;
    }
    [$ciphertext, $auth_tag,$aad,$key, $iv] = array_map('hex2bin',$securities);
    $plaintext = AESGCM::decrypt($ciphertext, $auth_tag, $aad, $key, $iv);
    return "Character Count - ".strlen($plaintext)."   ".$plaintext;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use built-in openssl for encryption?

Comment: For AES/GCM there is no limit to the plaintext length (you may be confusing this with asymmetric encryption like RSA, where the key size limits the plaintext length). Also the library you used works properly, i.e. for plaintexts of any lengths (at least on my machine). Maybe the problem is with writing to/reading from the database. You should separate both problems, i.e. encrypt/decrypt data without DB involvement (with long plaintexts) and check if the correct data is read from the DB when decrypting. Also you should post the exact error message/stacktrace. By the way, AES uses a 16 bytes IV.

Comment: @Topaco Sorry I forgot post exact error I update post now I posted error I see on decrypting

Comment: @MichaelFehr Using this library makes encrypting and decrypting easier for me I'm not familiar with cryptography so much so I need a library which AES-GCM is implemented correctly for encryption and ecryption.

Comment: @Topaco Is there any problem with sending cipher text, IV and Auth_Tag to database? Am I encoding them with wrong method before inserting?

Comment: Your code cannot be easily reproduced because of the database involvement. You should determine and post the values for the plaintext, `$bsCipher`, `$bsAAD`, `$bsKey`, `$bsIV` and `$bsTag` during encryption and the value of the `$securities` array during decryption (by debugging or logging). Of course with test data. Then it is possible to see if the data is consistent during encryption and decryption or if it was changed during database access and also to test the encryption/decryption independently of the database.

Comment: @Topaco Oh alright I got it now what you say. Thank you sir I will do it. This question might be unrelated, but do you think VARCHAR or LONGTEXT for field that CipherText is going to be saved is good?

Comment: Before storing, the data (including the ciphertext) is hex encoded with `bin2hex`, i.e. into a string with alphanumeric digits. This can of course be stored as text. But it must be noted that the length doubles, so a 16 bytes values needs hex encoded 32 bytes. This is important with regard to `VARCHAR`, because here a length must be specified which must be sufficient. Otherwise there should be no problem (`VARCHAR` allows lengths up to about 64 KiB, `LONGTEXT` up to about 4 GiB, see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-types.html)).

Comment: @Topaco Yeah that was the problem I was used 256 length for VARCHAR so I changed it into LongText I don't know if this is good idea or not but up to this point issue is solved.